# TimeoutException by java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add (FinalizerReference.java:61)

Tags: android

An app has the following exception occasionally

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
  at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add (FinalizerReference.java:61)
  at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize (BinderInternal.java:63)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:289)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:276)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:137)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

It is rare.  It happens only on Lenovo and Huawei devices. Could anyone shed some light on the possible cause of this crash?